# Adding a footer in itextsharp c#

Tags: c#, itext

I'm trying to add a footer to my generated PDF using itextsharp.

The document is created like so:

```
var document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 50, 50, 25, 25);
//add text and images
document.Add(new Paragraph(document.BottomMargin, "footer text"));
```

The problem is that because the text and images only fill about half the page the "footer text" is shown directly under that, and not at the foot of the document. The text and images in the document may change, so the footer needs to relate to the bottom of the doc and not the bottom of the content.

Any help greatly appreciated in how to do this.

Thanks,
NL

Comment: @Oded the same as with the `asp.net` tag => the connection is inexistent.

Comment: The code is in an ASP.NET Web Pages (razor syntax) page. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: @Oded, it doesn't really matter as it brings no value neither to the question nor it would help any probable answerers.

Comment: Here's an example of how you could [create a footer](http://www.mazsoft.com/blog/post/2008/04/30/Code-sample-for-using-iTextSharp-PDF-library.aspx) (*Page X of Y* added to the footer in this example).